# Python&OpenCv TypeError on Object Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, object-detection, opencv

I want to detect my ears on python&OpenCv but it occured this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/ImageProcessing/app.py", line 17, in <module>
cv2.rectangle(frame, obj, (15 ,15 ), (0, 0, 255),-5)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code is here :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ear = cv2.imread("ear.png", 0)
w, h = ear.shape[::-1]

while (True):
    _, frame = camera.read(0)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    match = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, ear, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    match = np.where(match >= 0.8)

    for obj in zip(match[::-1]):         
         print(obj)
         cv2.rectangle(frame, obj, (15,15), (0, 0, 255),-5)

    cv2.imshow("FindMyEars", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should i am to correct the code?

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem

Wrong :

```
for obj in zip(match[::-1]):
```

Right:

```
for obj in zip(match[*::-1]):
```